# How to change one of the two `StorageDoubleMap` keys?

Tags: storage, storagemap

Say I have a StorageDoubleMap like this

```
pub type Users<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<_, Twox64Concat, Vec<u8>, Twox64Concat, Compact<u64>, Person<T::AccountId>,>;
```

where the `key1 = Vec<u8>`, `key2 = Compact<u64>`. For example I store it like `<Users<T>>::insert(b"hello", 100, person);`

What if I want to change `key1` from `hello` to `new_hello`?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is first [take](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.StorageDoubleMap.html#method.take) a value from storage, removing it afterwards, and [insert](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.StorageDoubleMap.html#method.insert) it again with the new key:

```rs
    let value = <Users<T>>::take(b"hello", 100).ok_or(Error::<T>::UserDoesntExist)?;
    /// Insert it
    <Users<T>>::insert(b"new_hello", 100, value);
```

Comment: Oh nice, take is clever, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/trait.IterableStorageDoubleMap.html#tymethod.drain_prefix

I think you could write something like this to mutate the entire prefix tree:

```rs
for (k, v) in X::drain_prefix(old_prefix) {
  X::insert(new_prefix, k, v);
}
```

But this might cost a lot of weight. Be careful with that.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see this function.